# A generic theory in statistics/probability that quantifies the confidence for the maxima/minima produced by global optimization tools?

Tags: probability, statistics, optimization, monte-carlo

When using global optimization tools such as  Python's scipy or Mathematica's fmin,  I was informed that the results returned from the tool may not be accurate since the problem of finding global minimum/maximum seems to be intractable.

Now, I would like to know whether there is a generic theory in statistics/probability that quantifies the confidence for the maxima/minima these kinds of tool produce.  For example, if I use an Monte Carlo algorithm combined with Newton's gradient search, of how much probability can I claim the minimum found by the algorithm? Isn't there a theory studying this?

[EDITS] If there is no generic theory, maybe there is one that works for some category of functions? The difficulty for me is that my functions are computer programs, so linearity of convexity make little sense for my cases. Still I would like to learn about theoretical results for some specific categories of functions.

Comment: Simulated annealing converges to the optimum with probability $1$, but that has limited value for mortals.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you are trying to minimize an arbitrary function on a discrete set with $M$ elements, using $N$ random trials (Monte Carlo) and declaring the smallest result to be the minimum. The probability that this is the correct minimum is $\frac{N}{M}$.

Obviously this may be arbitrarily small.

Comment: Note that you implicitly assume the $N$ trials to be without repetition for $P = \frac NM$ to hold, so actually writing an algorithm for it is going to be very cumbersome. Also, for a 64-bit double that would mean $P = N \cdot 2^{-64}$, so to even be exact with $50\%$ probability you would need to sample $2^{63}$ times without replacement. This is currently intractible for average-joe computers, while numerical algorithms are and deliver much better results :D

Comment: Thanks Hans. N/M is too small most of the time. Is that the best one can get?

Comment: For arbitrary functions it is impossible to do better. For Lipschitz continuous functions however :)

Comment: @LinAlg Thanks. Do you mean that there are better, guaranteed  results with lipschitz continuous functions? Do you have references?

Comment: See for example http://www.cas.mcmaster.ca/~cs777/presentations/1_GO_Jonathan_LGO_Xie_BARON.pdf